# Importing code from file into Python and adding file dialog box

Tags: python

I have a python script signalgen.py that plays audio using equations but I would like to be able to hard code the file where the equation is stored in eq1.txt or choose a file and import the equation.
The problems I'm having are:

1) How can I hard code a file and it's path correctly so it will play the equation as audio

I get an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "signalgen.py", line 484, in need_data
    v += (datum * self.sig_level)
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

The specific block of code which I believe is causing the issue

```
def equation_import_function(self,t,f):
    fileobj=open("/home/rat/eq1.txt","r")
    eqdata =fileobj.read() #read whole file
    fileobj.close()
    #return math.tan(2.0*math.pi*f*t)
    return eqdata
```

I have this line of code in the eq1.txt file-> math.tan(2.0*math.pi*f*t)

2) How can I add a file open dialog box to be able to choose a file and import the equation.

PS I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 (Linux) and the equations will be several pages long this is the reason I would like to import them into python from text files

Here's the entire code if you want to look at what I'm using below or seen on pastebin which includes line numbers http://pastebin.com/HZg0Jhaw

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# ***************************************************************************
# *   Copyright (C) 2011, Paul Lutus                                        *
# *                                                                         *
# *   This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify  *
# *   it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by  *
# *   the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or     *
# *   (at your option) any later version.                                   *
# *                                                                         *
# *   This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,       *
# *   but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of        *
# *   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the         *
# *   GNU General Public License for more details.                          *
# *                                                                         *
# *   You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License     *
# *   along with this program; if not, write to the                         *
# *   Free Software Foundation, Inc.,                                       *
# *   59 Temple Place - Suite 330, Boston, MA  02111-1307, USA.             *
# ***************************************************************************

# version date 01-12-2011

VERSION = '1.1'

import re, sys, os

import gobject
gobject.threads_init()
import gst
import gtk
gtk.gdk.threads_init()
import time
import struct
import math
import random
import signal
import webbrowser

class Icon:
  icon = [
    "32 32 17 1",
    "   c None",
    ".  c #2A2E30",
    "+  c #333739",
    "@  c #464A4C",
    "#  c #855023",
    "$  c #575A59",
    "%  c #676A69",
    "&  c #CC5B00",
    "*  c #777A78",
    "=  c #DB731A",
    "-  c #8A8C8A",
    ";  c #969895",
    ">  c #F68C22",
    ",  c #A5A7A4",
    "'  c #F49D4A",
    ")  c #B3B5B2",
    "!  c #DEE0DD",
    "                        &&&&&&& ",
    "                  &&&===='''''& ",
    "                  &'''''====&'& ",
    "             +++++&'&&&&&   &'& ",
    "          +@$%****&'&+      &'& ",
    "        +@**%$@++@&'&*@+    &'& ",
    "      +@**@+++++++&'&@**@+  &'& ",
    "     +$*$+++++++++&'&++$*$+ &'& ",
    "     @*@++++++++++&'&+++@#&&&'& ",
    "    +*@++++++++#&&&'&+++#=''''& ",
    "   +*$++++++++#=''''&+++&'>>>'& ",
    "   @*+++++++++&'>>>'&+++#='''=  ",
    "  +%$++++++++@#='''=#@@++#&&&#  ",
    "  +*@+++++++@@@#&&&#@@@@@++@*+  ",
    "  +*+++++++@@@@++@$%$$@@@@++*+  ",
    "  +*++++++@@+@;,,*@@*$$$@@@+*+  ",
    "  +*@++++@@@%!!!!,;@$*$$$@@@*+  ",
    "  +%$++++@@+)!!!),-*+-%$$$@$%+  ",
    "  +@*+++@@@+-!!!,;-%@;%%$$+*@+  ",
    "   +*@++@@@@+$*-*%@+*-%%$@@*+   ",
    "   ++*@+@@@$$%@++@%;;*%%$@-$+   ",
    "    +@%+@@@$$%*;;;;-*%%%@**+    ",
    "    .+$%@@@$$$*******%$$*-+.    ",
    "     .+@%%@@$$*@*@%%%$%-%+.     ",
    "      .++@%$$$$$$%%%%--@+.      ",
    "        +++@@$%*****%+++        ",
    "         +++++++++++++@.        ",
    "          @--%@++@$*-%+         ",
    "           +%,))),;%+.          ",
    "             ++++++.            ",
    "                                ",
    "                                "
  ]

# this should be a temporary hack

class WidgetFinder:
  def localize_widgets(self,parent,xmlfile):
    # an unbelievable hack made necessary by
    # someone unwilling to fix a year-old bug
    with open(xmlfile) as f:
      for name in re.findall('(?s) id="(.*?)"',f.read()):
        if re.search('^k_',name):
          obj = parent.builder.get_object(name)
          setattr(parent,name,obj)

class ConfigManager:
  def __init__(self,path,dic):
    self.path = path
    self.dic = dic

  def read_config(self):
    if os.path.exists(self.path):
      with open(self.path) as f:
        for record in f.readlines():
          se = re.search('(.*?)\s*=\s*(.*)',record.strip())
          if(se):
            key,value = se.groups()
            if (key in self.dic):
              widget = self.dic[key]
              typ = type(widget)
              if(typ == list):
                widget[0] = value
              elif(typ == gtk.Entry):
                widget.set_text(value)
              elif(typ == gtk.HScale):
                widget.set_value(float(value))
              elif(typ == gtk.Window):
                w,h = value.split(',')
                widget.resize(int(w),int(h))
              elif(typ == gtk.CheckButton or typ == gtk.RadioButton or typ == gtk.ToggleButton):
                widget.set_active(value == 'True')
              elif(typ == gtk.ComboBox):
                if(value in widget.datalist):
                  i = widget.datalist.index(value)
                  widget.set_active(i)
              else:
                print "ERROR: reading, cannot identify key %s with type %s" % (key,type(widget))

  def write_config(self):
    with open(self.path,'w') as f:
      for key,widget in sorted(self.dic.iteritems()):
        typ = type(widget)
        if(typ == list):
          value = widget[0]
        elif(typ == gtk.Entry):
          value = widget.get_text()
        elif(typ == gtk.HScale):
          value = str(widget.get_value())
        elif(typ == gtk.Window):
          _,_,w,h = widget.get_allocation()
          value = "%d,%d" % (w,h)
        elif(typ == gtk.CheckButton or typ == gtk.RadioButton or typ == gtk.ToggleButton):
          value = ('False','True')[widget.get_active()]
        elif(typ == gtk.ComboBox):
          value = widget.get_active_text()
        else:
          print "ERROR: writing, cannot identify key %s with type %s" % (key,type(widget))
          value = "Error"
        f.write("%s = %s\n" % (key,value))

  def preset_combobox(self,box,v):
    if(v in box.datalist):
      i = box.datalist.index(v)
      box.set_active(i)
    else:
      box.set_active(0)

  def load_combobox(self,obj,data):
    if(len(obj.get_cells()) == 0):
      # Create a text cell renderer
      cell = gtk.CellRendererText ()
      obj.pack_start(cell)
      obj.add_attribute (cell, "text", 0)
    obj.get_model().clear()
    for s in data:
      obj.append_text(s.strip())
    setattr(obj,'datalist',data)

class TextEntryController:
  def __init__(self,parent,widget):
    self.par = parent
    self.widget = widget
    widget.connect('scroll-event',self.scroll_event)
    widget.set_tooltip_text('Enter number or:\n\
    Mouse wheel: increase,decrease\n\
    Shift/Ctrl/Alt: faster change')

  def scroll_event(self,w,evt):
    q = (-1,1)[evt.direction == gtk.gdk.SCROLL_UP]
    # magnify change if shift,ctrl,alt pressed
    for m in (1,2,4):
      if(self.par.mod_key_val & m): q *= 10
    s = self.widget.get_text()
    v = float(s)
    v += q
    v = max(0,v)
    s = self.par.format_num(v)
    self.widget.set_text(s)

class SignalGen:
  M_AM,M_FM = range(2)
  W_SINE,W_TRIANGLE,W_SQUARE,W_SAWTOOTH,W_EQUATION_IMPORT = range(5)
  waveform_strings = ('Sine','Triangle','Square','Sawtooth', 'Equation_Import')
  R_48000,R_44100,R_22050,R_16000,R_11025,R_8000,R_4000 = range(7)
  sample_rates = ('48000','44100','22050','16000', '11025', '8000', '4000')
  def __init__(self):
    self.restart = False
    # exit correctly on system signals
    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, self.close)
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, self.close)
    # precompile struct operator
    self.struct_int = struct.Struct('i')
    self.max_level = (2.0**31)-1
    self.gen_functions = (
      self.sine_function,
      self.triangle_function,
      self.square_function,
      self.sawtooth_function,
      self.equation_import_function
    )
    self.main_color = gtk.gdk.color_parse('#c04040')
    self.sig_color = gtk.gdk.color_parse('#40c040')
    self.mod_color = gtk.gdk.color_parse('#4040c0')
    self.noise_color = gtk.gdk.color_parse('#c040c0')
    self.pipeline = False
    self.count = 0
    self.imod = 0
    self.rate = 1
    self.mod_key_val = 0
    self.sig_freq = 440
    self.mod_freq = 3
    self.sig_level = 100
    self.mod_level = 100
    self.noise_level = 100
    self.enable = True
    self.sig_waveform = SignalGen.W_SINE
    self.sig_enable = True
    self.sig_function = False
    self.mod_waveform = SignalGen.W_SINE
    self.mod_function = False
    self.mod_mode = SignalGen.M_AM
    self.mod_enable = False
    self.noise_enable = False
    self.sample_rate = SignalGen.R_22050
    self.left_audio  = True
    self.right_audio = True
    self.program_name = self.__class__.__name__
    self.config_file = os.path.expanduser("~/." + self.program_name)
    self.builder = gtk.Builder()
    self.xmlfile = 'signalgen_gui.glade'
    self.builder.add_from_file(self.xmlfile)
    WidgetFinder().localize_widgets(self,self.xmlfile)
    self.k_quit_button.connect('clicked',self.close)
    self.k_help_button.connect('clicked',self.launch_help)
    self.k_mainwindow.connect('destroy',self.close)
    self.k_mainwindow.set_icon(gtk.gdk.pixbuf_new_from_xpm_data(Icon.icon))
    self.title = self.program_name + ' ' + VERSION
    self.k_mainwindow.set_title(self.title)
    self.tooltips = {
      self.k_sample_rate_combobox : 'Change data sampling rate',
      self.k_left_checkbutton : 'Enable left channel audio',
      self.k_right_checkbutton : 'Enable right channel audio',
      self.k_sig_waveform_combobox : 'Select signal waveform',
      self.k_mod_waveform_combobox : 'Select modulation waveform',
      self.k_mod_enable_checkbutton  : 'Enable modulation',
      self.k_sig_enable_checkbutton  : 'Enable signal',
      self.k_noise_enable_checkbutton  : 'Enable white noise',
      self.k_mod_am_radiobutton : 'Enable amplitude modulation',
      self.k_mod_fm_radiobutton : 'Enable frequency modulation',
      self.k_quit_button : 'Quit %s' % self.title,
      self.k_enable_checkbutton : 'Enable output',
      self.k_help_button : 'Visit the %s Web page' % self.title,
    }
    for k,v in self.tooltips.iteritems():
      k.set_tooltip_text(v)
    self.config_data = {
      'SampleRate' : self.k_sample_rate_combobox,
      'LeftChannelEnabled' : self.k_left_checkbutton,
      'RightChannelEnabled' : self.k_right_checkbutton,
      'SignalWaveform' : self.k_sig_waveform_combobox,
      'SignalFrequency' : self.k_sig_freq_entry,
      'SignalLevel' : self.k_sig_level_entry,
      'SignalEnabled' : self.k_sig_enable_checkbutton,
      'ModulationWaveform' : self.k_mod_waveform_combobox,
      'ModulationFrequency' : self.k_mod_freq_entry,
      'ModulationLevel' : self.k_mod_level_entry,
      'ModulationEnabled' : self.k_mod_enable_checkbutton,
      'AmplitudeModulation' : self.k_mod_am_radiobutton,
      'FrequencyModulation' : self.k_mod_fm_radiobutton,
      'NoiseEnabled' : self.k_noise_enable_checkbutton,
      'NoiseLevel' : self.k_noise_level_entry,
      'OutputEnabled' : self.k_enable_checkbutton,
    }
    self.cm = ConfigManager(self.config_file,self.config_data)
    self.cm.load_combobox(self.k_sig_waveform_combobox,self.waveform_strings)
    self.k_sig_waveform_combobox.set_active(self.sig_waveform)
    self.cm.load_combobox(self.k_mod_waveform_combobox,self.waveform_strings)
    self.k_mod_waveform_combobox.set_active(self.mod_waveform)
    self.cm.load_combobox(self.k_sample_rate_combobox,self.sample_rates)
    self.k_sample_rate_combobox.set_active(self.sample_rate)
    self.k_sig_freq_entry.set_text(self.format_num(self.sig_freq))
    self.k_sig_level_entry.set_text(self.format_num(self.sig_level))
    self.k_mod_freq_entry.set_text(self.format_num(self.mod_freq))
    self.k_mod_level_entry.set_text(self.format_num(self.mod_level))
    self.k_noise_level_entry.set_text(self.format_num(self.noise_level))
    self.k_main_viewport_border.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL,self.main_color)
    self.k_sig_viewport_border.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL,self.sig_color)
    self.k_mod_viewport_border.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL,self.mod_color)
    self.k_noise_viewport_border.modify_bg(gtk.STATE_NORMAL,self.noise_color)
    self.sig_freq_cont = TextEntryController(self,self.k_sig_freq_entry)
    self.sig_level_cont = TextEntryController(self,self.k_sig_level_entry)
    self.mod_freq_cont = TextEntryController(self,self.k_mod_freq_entry)
    self.mod_level_cont = TextEntryController(self,self.k_mod_level_entry)
    self.noise_level_cont = TextEntryController(self,self.k_noise_level_entry)
    self.k_mainwindow.connect('key-press-event',self.key_event)
    self.k_mainwindow.connect('key-release-event',self.key_event)
    self.k_enable_checkbutton.connect('toggled',self.update_values)
    self.k_sig_freq_entry.connect('changed',self.update_entry_values)
    self.k_sig_level_entry.connect('changed',self.update_entry_values)
    self.k_sig_enable_checkbutton.connect('toggled',self.update_checkbutton_values)
    self.k_mod_freq_entry.connect('changed',self.update_entry_values)
    self.k_mod_level_entry.connect('changed',self.update_entry_values)
    self.k_noise_level_entry.connect('changed',self.update_entry_values)
    self.k_sample_rate_combobox.connect('changed',self.update_values)
    self.k_sig_waveform_combobox.connect('changed',self.update_values)
    self.k_mod_waveform_combobox.connect('changed',self.update_values)
    self.k_left_checkbutton.connect('toggled',self.update_checkbutton_values)
    self.k_right_checkbutton.connect('toggled',self.update_checkbutton_values)
    self.k_mod_enable_checkbutton.connect('toggled',self.update_checkbutton_values)
    self.k_noise_enable_checkbutton.connect('toggled',self.update_checkbutton_values)
    self.k_mod_am_radiobutton.connect('toggled',self.update_checkbutton_values)
    self.cm.read_config()
    self.update_entry_values()
    self.update_checkbutton_values()
    self.update_values()

  def format_num(self,v):
    return "%.2f" % v

  def get_widget_text(self,w):
    typ = type(w)
    if(typ == gtk.ComboBox):
      return w.get_active_text()
    elif(typ == gtk.Entry):
      return w.get_text()

  def get_widget_num(self,w):
    try:
      return float(self.get_widget_text(w))
    except:
      return 0.0

  def restart_test(self,w,pv):
    nv = w.get_active()
    self.restart |= (nv != pv)
    return nv

  def update_entry_values(self,*args):
    self.sig_freq = self.get_widget_num(self.k_sig_freq_entry)
    self.sig_level = self.get_widget_num(self.k_sig_level_entry) / 100.0
    self.mod_freq = self.get_widget_num(self.k_mod_freq_entry)
    self.mod_level = self.get_widget_num(self.k_mod_level_entry) / 100.0
    self.noise_level = self.get_widget_num(self.k_noise_level_entry) / 100.0

  def update_checkbutton_values(self,*args):
    self.left_audio = self.k_left_checkbutton.get_active()
    self.right_audio = self.k_right_checkbutton.get_active()
    self.mod_enable = self.k_mod_enable_checkbutton.get_active()
    self.sig_enable = self.k_sig_enable_checkbutton.get_active()
    self.mod_mode = (SignalGen.M_FM,SignalGen.M_AM)[self.k_mod_am_radiobutton.get_active()]
    self.noise_enable = self.k_noise_enable_checkbutton.get_active()

  def update_values(self,*args):
    self.restart = (not self.sig_function)
    self.sample_rate = self.restart_test(self.k_sample_rate_combobox, self.sample_rate)
    self.enable = self.restart_test(self.k_enable_checkbutton,self.enable)
    self.mod_waveform = self.k_mod_waveform_combobox.get_active()
    self.mod_function = self.gen_functions[self.mod_waveform]
    self.sig_waveform = self.k_sig_waveform_combobox.get_active()
    self.sig_function = self.gen_functions[self.sig_waveform]
    self.k_sample_rate_combobox.set_sensitive(not self.enable)
    if(self.restart):
      self.init_audio()

  def make_and_chain(self,name):
    target = gst.element_factory_make(name)
    self.chain.append(target)
    return target

  def unlink_gst(self):
    if(self.pipeline):
      self.pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)
      self.pipeline.remove_many(*self.chain)
      gst.element_unlink_many(*self.chain)
      for item in self.chain:
        item = False
      self.pipeline = False
      time.sleep(0.01)

  def init_audio(self):
    self.unlink_gst()
    if(self.enable):
      self.chain = []
      self.pipeline = gst.Pipeline("mypipeline")
      self.source = self.make_and_chain("appsrc")
      rs = SignalGen.sample_rates[self.sample_rate]
      self.rate = float(rs)
      self.interval = 1.0 / self.rate
      caps = gst.Caps(
      'audio/x-raw-int,'
      'endianness=(int)1234,'
      'channels=(int)2,'
      'width=(int)32,'
      'depth=(int)32,'
      'signed=(boolean)true,'
      'rate=(int)%s' % rs)
      self.source.set_property('caps', caps)
      self.sink = self.make_and_chain("autoaudiosink")
      self.pipeline.add(*self.chain)
      gst.element_link_many(*self.chain)
      self.source.connect('need-data', self.need_data)
      self.pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)

  def key_event(self,w,evt):
    cn = gtk.gdk.keyval_name(evt.keyval)
    if(re.search('Shift',cn) != None):
      mod = 1
    elif(re.search('Control',cn) != None):
      mod = 2
    elif(re.search('Alt|Meta',cn) != None):
      mod = 4
    else:
      return
    if(evt.type == gtk.gdk.KEY_PRESS):
      self.mod_key_val |= mod
    else:
      self.mod_key_val &= ~mod

  def sine_function(self,t,f):
    return math.sin(2.0*math.pi*f*t)



  def triangle_function(self,t,f):
    q = 4*math.fmod(t*f,1)
    q = (q,2-q)[q > 1]
    return (q,-2-q)[q < -1]

  def square_function(self,t,f):
    if(f == 0): return 0
    q = 0.5 - math.fmod(t*f,1)
    return (-1,1)[q > 0]

  def sawtooth_function(self,t,f):
    return 2.0*math.fmod((t*f)+0.5,1.0)-1.0

  def equation_import_function(self,t,f):
    fileobj=open("/home/rat/eq1.txt","r")
    eqdata =fileobj.read() #read whole file
    fileobj.close()
    #return math.tan(2.0*math.pi*f*t)
    return eqdata

  def need_data(self,src,length):
    bytes = ""
    # sending two channels, so divide requested length by 2
    ld2 = length / 2
    for tt in range(ld2):
      t = (self.count + tt) * self.interval
      if(not self.mod_enable):
        datum = self.sig_function(t,self.sig_freq)
      else:
        mod = self.mod_function(t,self.mod_freq)
        # AM mode
        if(self.mod_mode == SignalGen.M_AM):
          datum = 0.5 * self.sig_function(t,self.sig_freq) * (1.0 + (mod * self.mod_level))
        # FM mode
        else:
          self.imod += (mod * self.mod_level * self.interval)
          datum = self.sig_function(t+self.imod,self.sig_freq)
      v = 0
      if(self.sig_enable):
        v += (datum * self.sig_level)
      if(self.noise_enable):
        noise = ((2.0 * random.random()) - 1.0)
        v += noise * self.noise_level
      v *= self.max_level
      v = max(-self.max_level,v)
      v = min(self.max_level,v)
      left  = (0,v)[self.left_audio]
      right = (0,v)[self.right_audio]
      bytes += self.struct_int.pack(left)
      bytes += self.struct_int.pack(right)
    self.count += ld2
    src.emit('push-buffer', gst.Buffer(bytes))

  def launch_help(self,*args):
    webbrowser.open("http://arachnoid.com/python/signalgen_program.html")

  def close(self,*args):
    self.unlink_gst()
    self.cm.write_config()
    gtk.main_quit()

app=SignalGen()
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was commenting before, but I stared at your code long enough and kinda realized what you were trying to do, so it was easier for me to post an answer. Please refer to cJ Zougloubs answer as I expand on his suggestion to use the imp module. 
Your equation files should implement a common interface:

```
# equation1.py
def eqn(*args):
    return sum(*args)
```

Then you would load them in using cj Zougloubs suggestion, but with a common interface:

```
# python_rt.py
def equation_import_function(self, *args):
    filepath = ''
    # filepath = ... do file chooser dialog here ...

    eq_mod = imp.load_source("equation", filepath)
    eqdata = eq_mod.eqn(*args)
    return eqdata
```

Now you have a function in your main code that takes any number of arguments, asks the user to pick the equation file, and gets the result for you.

**Edit** To address your comment more specifically

```
# equation1.py
import math

def eqn(*args):
    f = args[0]
    t = args[1]
    return math.tan(2.0*math.pi*f*t)
```

And in your main tool, you would use imp.load_source to bring it in. Wherever you needed that equation for your audio, you could then do:

```
eq_mod.eqn(f, t)
```

Comment: The 1st question that I still have is where do I put the equation math.tan(2.0*math.pi*f*t) line in the equation1.py file so it will play the equation as audio?

Answer (score 2):

The `imp` module will help you to cleanly load Python code chunks from arbitrary files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# equation in equation-one.py
def eqn(arg):
    return arg * 3 + 2

#!/usr/bin/env python
# your code

import imp
path = "equation-one.py"
eq_mod = imp.load_source("equation", path, open(path))

print("Oh the nice stuff in eq_mod: %s" % dir(eq_mod))
```

In your custom function definition, you can create a file selector dialog, get the selected file path, load the code using `imp`, and return the result of the function inside the imported module.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response but I'm a little confused at how this fits in the python script. Are you saying I need to get rid of (self,t,f): and don't use the fileobj?  Should I replace the equation math.tan(2.0*math.pi*f*t) with def eqn(math.tan(2.0*math.pi*f*t)): return ???

Comment: I think that what you want to do is import custom equations containing Python code (imp stuff) and choose the file to load (for which you can use http://pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-FileChoosers.html )

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for but when I put the lines 
def equation_import_function(self,t,f):
    return math.tan(2.0*math.pi*f*t)  
into the eq1.py file and add the lines 

import imp
eqpath = "eq1.py"
eq_mod = imp.load_source("equation", eqpath, open(eqpath))

It comes back with an error.  Maybe I should start with just hard coding the path in signalgen.py to the equation located in eq1.py to work first before I try and load a file with the FileChooser option.

Comment: Yes, you can also open a python prompt and play interactively with the code you don't master, to understand how it works

Comment: The thing is I can get it to work with it when it's directly in the file like this
def equation_import_function(self,t,f):
return math.tan(2.0*math.pi*f*t)

Just not when it tries to read the code from another file

Comment: He is saying to use the FileChooser FIRST, which will return the path to the file that the user selected. With that path string, you can then you imp.load_source() to process the file.

Comment: I started to type a lot here but decided to just post another answer that expands.